# ng2-dnd. How to get my DropZones which are under objects to be active when dragging.

Tags: html, angular, drag-and-drop

I have multiple drop zones which are relatively close together and some of the objects I am dragging to them cover more than just the one location it has been dropped on. I'm trying to find a way of making all the drop zones active while i'm dragging but not get in the way of picking up an object from them.

I tried having the drop zones layered on top of the objects and added in a css class (.not-displayed) to set display to none while nothing is being dragged but it seemed like it was still stopping me from dragging the object. I can click on the edge of the object and still drag fine but anywhere the drop zone was, stopped it from picking up.

I tried having the pointer events set to all while an object is being dragged and to none when nothing is moving but that didn't seem to help.

I tried changing the z-index to change the order of the layers but even though they appear to go, it still stops the dragging from working properly.

This is the HTML code to create my draggable objects:

```
<div *ngFor="let device of moves[sliderValue].devices"
   class="device-style"
   [ngStyle]="{'background-color':device.colour}"
   [style.width.px]="device.width * mapScale"
   [style.height.px]="device.height * mapScale"
   [style.left.px]="(device.locationX - (device.width/2)) * mapScale + offsetX"
   [style.top.px]="(device.locationY - (device.height/2)) * mapScale + offsetY"
   [style.transform]="'rotate(' + adjustDeviceRotation(device.deviceAngle) + 'deg)'"
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;"
   dnd-draggable
   [dragEnabled]="true"
   [dragData]="device"
   (onDragStart)="onDragStart($event, device)"
   (onDragEnd)="onDropFailure($event)">

   <div class="panel-body">
  <div [style.font-size.px]="70 * mapScale"
       [style.width.px]="device.width * mapScale"
       style="text-align: center;">{{device.ident}}</div>
</div>
```

And this is how I create my drop zones:

```
  <div *ngFor="let location of locations"
   class="drop-zone-locations"
   [style.left.px]="(location.locationX) * mapScale + offsetX - (100 * mapScale)"
   [style.top.px]="(location.locationY) * mapScale + offsetY - (100 * mapScale)"
   [style.border-radius.px]="(100 * mapScale)"
   [style.width.px]="200 * mapScale"
   [style.height.px]="200 * mapScale"
   [style.pointer-events]="pointerEventStatus"
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;"
   [class.not-displayed]="dragging == false"
   dnd-droppable
   (onDragEnter)="onDragEnter($event)"
   (onDropSuccess)="onDropSuccess($event, location)">
```

I've tried researching this but it seems like there's not much documentation on ng-2 dnd and everything I've attempted hasn't worked so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)